# .NET 5 WebAPI returning different format in local and when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, webapi

I am retrieving data from my database using WebAPI and displaying it in a page, but once I get the response in the browser, im getting invalid date in my local but correct date from the one deployed in Azure. I chcked the response and it happens because the one I get from local is in a different format even though I am using the same DB (copy of the Azure DB thats in my local) and code.

My questions are:

1. Where is the returned format based from? The server settings?
2. How can I make this consistent?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look at the code, probably you are getting the date from the server itself. In that case you need to change the App Service(if you are deployed on App service) time zone as described [**here**](https://sajeetharan.com/2019/11/12/how-to-set-timezone-in-azure-app-service/)